# Copy command calling macros from another file

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

My colleague asked me for help with a problem he's having: everytime he clicks "Copy" in the context menu, it tries to call a macro from a specific file.

- It happens only on his computer
- It happens on every .xls
- It always tries to search for the same file
- **It doesn't happen if he tries to copy with Ctrl+C**

What could trigger such behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like a bad **add-in**

Comment: The possible reason is,, your friend has customize the Menu and assigns some Macro to the Copy command on context Menu.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent tried that, no custom add-ins were installed

Comment: @RajeshS maybe... but I have no knowledge on how to do that. Do you know where I can find a tutorial?

Comment: @HDD,, just check the answer I've  posted will help you to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You refer this link, https://www.wintips.org/fix-copy-paste-not-working-in-word-excel-2007-2010-or-other-programs/

Even though the topic is related to the MS-Word but it's common with other Office  products including Excel.

**The solution 1**

**To check the Copy/Paste Commands on Home Tab follow these steps.**

- From Word's main menu (File), go to Options.
- Choose Customize Ribbon on the left.
- Then click at Customize button next to "Keyboard Shortcuts".
  At Customize Keyboard options, choose:
- At Categories > Home Tab
- At Commands > EditCopy

Now under Current keys you should have these two (2) shortcut keys by default.

- Ctrl+C
- Ctrl+Insert

If you don't have the above two key combinations, click at the "Press new shortcut key" box & then press the corresponding combination for the missing shortcut key (e.g. "Ctrl+C") and press Enter.

Perform the same operation for the EditCut * & EditPaste commands.*** In "EditCut" command you should have these two (2) shortcut keys by default.

- Ctrl+X
- Shift+Del

** In "EditPaste" command you should have these two (2) shortcut keys by default.

- Ctrl+V Shift+Insert
- When done, check if the "Copy Paste Not Working".

**The solution 2**

Sometimes there is a strange language matching to the OS language and such uncommon behaviour  can be seen.

- Open Excel. Click File then Options.
- Click on Language.
- Under the section titled "Choose Display and Help Languages", you can
  notice  the default being "Match Microsoft Windows".
- Select "English" in each box.
- Click on "Set as Default" Click on "OK".

**NB: You will be prompted to restart Excel, better you restart the Computer.
All keyboard Shortcuts will be restored to the default English ones after you restart.**

*I do hope this help you lot.*

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234,, its  working properly, just now I've tried the link.